# TBitmap.monochrome property equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, delphi, bitmap, equivalent, monochrome

I'm trying to convert a Delphi code to C# and I wonder if there's an equivalent of `VCL.Graphics.TBitmap.Monochrome` property in C#?

It's explanation it says: **Determines whether the bitmap displays its image in monochrome.
If Monochrome is true if the bitmap displays as a monochrome bitmap. Monochrome is false if the bitmap displays in color, that is, if it contains more than one bit per pixel.**

and C# doesn't have something like this I think.

If there's a workaround for this, what is it and how can it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Which .NET class are you using as the equivalent for `VCL.Graphics.TBitmap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delphi one refers to the drawing of the image, so the equivilant is setting the [ImageAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You just need to find a colour matrix for monochome.

Comment: can you give an example with/without a colormatrix?

Comment: @tpaksu follow the link, that has an example.

Comment: I know. I just thought you might add some more to your answer.